# Workday Human Resources API - Invalid request service version

Tags: soap, workday-api

I'm trying to make an example GET request to the Get_Employee endpoint but I am receiving an "Invalid request service version" error.

I followed the WorkDay provided tutorial and it is still not working: https://community.workday.com/articles/6120?page=1.

This is the endpoint that I am hitting: https://services1.myworkday.com/ccx/service/MYTENANTNAME/Human_Resources/v32.1

I expected to receive an XML payload and am instead receiving the following error

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc">
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client.validationError</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Invalid request service version</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that the version that you're specifying in the first node within `soapenv:Body` is referencing the version that you're submitting the request to. In my example below, you'll see it as an attribute in the `bsvc:Get_Change_Work_Contact_Information_Request` node below:

```
   <soapenv:Header>
      <bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
         <bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>false</bsvc:Include_Reference_Descriptors_In_Response>
      </bsvc:Workday_Common_Header>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bsvc:Get_Change_Work_Contact_Information_Request bsvc:version="v31.2">
         <bsvc:Request_References>
            <bsvc:Person_Reference>
               <bsvc:ID bsvc:type="Employee_ID">139420</bsvc:ID>
            </bsvc:Person_Reference>
         </bsvc:Request_References>
      </bsvc:Get_Change_Work_Contact_Information_Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response I was definitely missing this.... I'm getting an authentication error now, the credentials you use to log in to Workday Community will be the same you use to make these API calls correct? Will accept this as the correct answer when I can get it completely working....

Comment: @GeorgeWright Great! I'm glad this was it. As for your auth issue, make sure that you're using `username@tenantname` instead of just your username.

Comment: The credentials are not the same as your community login. It is the Workday Account and password set up in Workday, not the same as you SSO password if you have that set up.